# Nagios Custom Script for finding defunct processes

Tags: linux, ksh, nagios

Objective: Check for zombie processes, but if any are found to be owned by the account nagios, ignore them.  If a zombie process is found to be owned by an account other than the nagios account, then issue an alert.

Currently have the following nagios check in the nrds.cfg to find zombie processes.

`command[Check_ZombieProcs]=/opt/tools/nagitem/libexec/check_procs -w 1 -c 2 -s Z`

Which will generate output like this when it finds something:

`PROCS CRITICAL: 3 processes with STATE = Z | procs=3;1;2;0;`

To find out who owns the above following 3 defunct zombie processes, I can manually run the command:
ps -elf | grep Z | grep "defunct" which results in the output shown below.

`0 Z nagios     9487   9948  0  80   0 -     0 do_exi Nov07 ?        00:00:00 [sh] <defunct>`

`0 Z nagios    28647   9949  0  80   0 -     0 do_exi Nov03 ?        00:00:00 [sh] <defunct>`

`0 Z nagios    67429   9947  0  80   0 -     0 do_exi Nov03 ?        00:00:00 [sh] <defunct>`

My problem is that the defunct processes shown above end up clearing on their own and I want to exclude from the output any defunct zombie processes owned by the account **nagios**.
Since the check_procs nagios plugin does not have an argument to handle the exclusion of a user, I am creating the following script.

With the script below, what I want to accomplish is:
If status is equal to null or is equal to nagios, then state should be ok (green).
If status is equal to anything other than null or nagios, then state should be critcal (red).

```
#!/bin/ksh

STATE_OK=0
STATE_WARNING=1
STATE_CRITICAL=2
STATE_UNKNOWN=3
SCRIPTPATH=`echo $0 | /bin/sed -e 's,[\\/][^\\/][^\\/]*$,,'`
if [[ -f ${SCRIPTPATH}/utils.sh ]]; then
        . ${SCRIPTPATH}/utils.sh # use nagios utils to set real STATE_* return values
fi

printvariables() {
        echo "Variables:"
        #Add all your variables at the end of the "for" line to display them in verbose
        for i in  EXITSTATUS EXITMESSAGE
        do
                echo -n "$i : "
                eval echo \$${i}
        done
        echo
}

#Set to unknown in case of unexpected exit
EXITSTATUS=$STATE_UNKNOWN
EXITMESSAGE="UNKNOWN: Unexpected exit. You should check that everything is alright"

ZOMB=$(ps -elf | grep Z | grep "defunct" | awk {'print $3'} | sort -u)

if [ "$ZOMB" == "nagios" ];then
   EXITSTATUS=$STATE_OK
   EXITMESSAGE="OK - No Defunct processes found"
elif [ "$ZOMB" == "" ];then
   EXITSTATUS=$STATE_OK
   EXITMESSAGE="OK - No Defunct processes found"
else
   EXITSTATUS=$STATE_CRITICAL
   EXITMESSAGE="CRITICAL - Defunct processes found owned by $ZOMB"
fi

#Script end, display verbose information
if [[ $VERBOSE -eq 1 ]] ; then
        printvariables
fi

echo ${EXITMESSAGE}
exit $EXITSTATUS
```

The command:

```
ps -elf | grep Z | grep "defunct" | awk {'print $3'}
```

has the potential to give output similar to the following which no doubt will cause an issue. I cannot replicate or thoroughly test as I only occasionally see a defunct process.

```
nagios
root
someuser
```

**Note** that in my script above I am using (see the sort -u):

```
ps -elf | grep Z | grep "defunct" | awk {'print $3'} | sort -u
```

to eliminate getting the same account (like nagios) listed multiple times in the output. My script above does work, but I am concerned that it cannot handle if there is more than one account that has defunct processes.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a bash question than a nagios question, but I'll bite.

The first issue I see is that you're simply pushing all output from `ps` into `$ZOMB` when what you probably want to do is to iterate over each line (process).

You could do something like this:

- For each line in the `ps` output, check if it's a zombie process. If not, discard it.
- If yes, check whether the user is `nagios`, if so discard it.
- If not, we have a problem, so exit 1 and say what the user and process is.

Example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(ps -elf)" | while IFS= read -r line ;
do
    user=$(echo "$line" | awk {'print $3'})
    stat=$(echo "$line" | awk {'print $2'})
    proc=$(echo "$line" | awk {'print $15'})
    if [ "$stat" != "R" ]; then
        # it's not running, we don't care
        continue
    elif [ "$user" == "root" ]; then
        # it's root, we don't care
        continue
    else
        # we do care! print info and exit 1 immediately
        echo "Found process: $user '$proc'"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

In your case, "R" would be "Z" and "root" would be "nagios".